# How to control databricks figure size

Tags: matplotlib, databricks

I'm trying to plot some figures from databricks , but can't seem to control the figure size . All the commented-out stuff doesn't do the trick , possibly as the plot is wrapped by 'display'.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, axes = plt.subplots(2,1)
axes[0].hist(deltas,bins=200,log=False) 
axes[0].set_title('hist')
axes[1].hist(deltas,bins=200,log=True)
axes[1].set_title('loghist')
plt.xlabel('epochtime')
#plt.figsize=(30,10)
#plt.figure(figsize=(30,30))
#plt.show()
#f.figsize=(30,20)
display(f,figsize=(30,20))
```

Anyone have the magic?

Comment: `f, axes = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(8,4))`

Comment: that does the trick